# Is * could have* mean speculation in the sentence below?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I would highly recommend that you continue your seats on wedding.com, as your life partner could have just registered.

Comment: I see that wedding.com is a website. But even with the sentence corrected like that, "continue your seats" still doesn't mean anything. Hm, did you mean "continue your search"?

Comment: @MrLister "seats" sounds like it refers to being a user on the website. Rather than delete your registration and go somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

... as something **could** have happened

Yes, **could** there is speculative in that it refers to something which might have taken place. There is no knowledge that it happened. It was possible.

Comment: Possibility percentage of them compared to could have with * may have & might have in the sentence mentioned above.

Comment: @Scottish: Sorry, I do not understand your comment.